# What rules are there in HTTP regarding the size of the response?

Tags: http

I'm unclear on what rules there are for a server when sending the response:

1. Is the `Content-Length` header required? Under what circumstances?
2. I think the answer to that is no. So how does the client detect when the response is complete without that header? The server could just disconnect, but that does not seem to work with keep-alive and pipelining.
3. Does HTTP support unbounded responses? Either truly infinite or with a size that is not known when sending headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers are in the HTTP spec, namely [RFC 7230, section 3.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3).

Comment: And might you be able to cite the relevant passages here too...?